# Javascript Updates fail

Tags: javascript, html

All,

Below is the simple code that updates the field with input entered by the user. However, the updates are not taking place. Can anyone please let me know the issue here?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Rooms</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function populate()
         {
            var newName = document.getElementsByName("roomNameInput").value;
            document.getElementsByName("nameDisplay").value = newName;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h3>Configure: </h3><i name="nameDisplay"></i><br />
      Enter the Room name: <input type="text" name="roomNameInput" onkeypress="populate()"><br />
   </body>
</html>
```

tried with `document.getElementsByName("nameDisplay").innerHTML` but fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML should be this

```
<h3>Configure: </h3>
       <em id="nameDisplay"></em><br />
      Enter the Room name: <input id="roomNameInput" type="text" onkeyup="populate()"><br />
```

Javascript should be this:

```
var populate = function(){
    var a = document.getElementById('roomNameInput').value;
    document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = a; 
}
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DarkThrone/B5LP7/

Answer (score 3):

`nameDisplay` is not a input, so you have to change its content by setting the `innerHTML` property, not `value`. Also `getElementsByName` will not work there, you have to set it's `id` to `nameDisplay`, and use `getElementById`

```
<i id="nameDisplay"></i>
```

...

```
document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = newName;
```

---

`getElementsByName` will return an array of elements, so you have to select the first element to get the value:

```
var newName = document.getElementsByName("roomNameInput").value;
```

You could also set the `id` value of the `input` and use `getElementById` to select it.

---

To make things simpler, use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) framework:

```
function populate() {
    var newName = $('[name="roomNameInput"]').val();
    $("#nameDisplay").text(newName);
}
```

Comment: made the changes .. getting undefined where I need to display the text entered.

Comment: Change `onkeypress="populate()"` to `onkeypress="populate"` - the double brace executes the function while assigning it as a handler

Comment: change roomNameInput to id as well

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsById()` returns an array of elements, so a quick fix would be to do the following:

```
var newName = document.getElementsByName("roomNameInput")[0].value;
document.getElementsByName("nameDisplay")[0].innerHTML = newName;
```

An even better solution would be to replace the `name` attribute with an `id` and replace `<i>` with `<em>` (since it's no longer standard):

```
<em id="nameDisplay"></em>
<input type="text" id="roomNameInput" onkeypress="populate()" />
```

Then switch up your JS:

```
var newName = document.getElementById("roomNameInput").value;
document.getElementById("nameDisplay")[0].innerHTML = newName;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to change:

```
document.getElementByName("nameDisplay").value = newName;
```

to

```
document.getElementByName("nameDisplay").innerHTML = newName;
```

---

but, if i can suggest, batter to make like:
in HTML:

```
<h3>Configure: </h3><span id="nameDisplay"></span><br />
```

then
in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = "<i>"+newName+"</i>";
```